# Does someone know what's the magic behind the Render-Tree?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

The Layer-Tree and Presentation-Tree are pretty clear. But the Render-Tree is not. Since it is private API and Apple doesn't talk much about it, I would still like to know more details about what's going on there. Does anyone know?

Comment: I wasn't even aware you were talking about core animation or the iPhone until I saw the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I went to google this and their documentation came up, to which I thought "Heck yes! I love Apple Documentation this is sure to have the answer he wants!"

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Art/layer_pres_render.jpg

:|

If Apple isn't telling, I don't think you're going to find much about it at all. This has me angered too, as you've caught my interest.

Comment: Thanks, I've stared at this picture for a couple of hours ;) it really doesn't tell anything. They wasted their time with this one.

Comment: I think it's hilarious that they went through the effort to make that though. I must admit, an empty dotted box would have been even more frustrating. I reckon your best luck would be contacting the 'underground' iPhone scene. They're pretty experienced at finding things, like this, that Apple neglects to mention.

Comment: Where would I find that "underground scene"? ;) maybe at the subway station? I hope some of these guys are here. C'mon Apple folks! Where are you? Employees have a life after work too, and I'm sure they hang a lot around here.

Comment: I'm talking about the people that do all the jailbreaking and things of questionable legality. Probably on various IRC channels, like most things nerdy and of questionable legality. You can bet you aren't going to hear a thing about it from an Employee of Apple. They like their job more than they like you knowing things.

Comment: It's a rendering engine implemented in OpenGl. Why don't you class dump the QuartzCore framework?